# RecycleView multiplebuttons should hold user id from volley and send user id to database on click of buttons

Tags: android, android-volley, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I created a RecyclerView with multiple buttons. Both buttons will hold user_id using volley with PHP and MySQL. But I am not able to send the user id when clicking the button of the particular user. I tried a lot but not able to do so.

Actually, there are 2 users with images and two buttons for each. Each button populated with user_id from Mysql database using PHP. Functionality is when I pressed a button the user_id of the particular user should go to the database and update into it which is not happening. Please tell me if anyone aware of how to resolve the issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    //this is the JSON Data URL
    //make sure you are using the correct ip else it will not work
    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://192.168.10.119/staradmin/andcustomerrequest.php";

    //a list to store all the products
    List<CustomerRequest> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CustomerRequestAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView mList;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        adapter = new CustomerRequestAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        loadProducts();

    }


    private void loadProducts(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray products = new JSONArray(response);
                            for(int i=0; i<products.length();i++){
                                JSONObject productObject = products.getJSONObject(i);
                                String user_id = productObject.getString("user_id");
                                String name = productObject.getString("name");
                                String price = productObject.getString("price");
                                //  String city = productObject.getString("city");
                                String image = productObject.getString("image");
                                String outletname = productObject.getString("outletname");

                                CustomerRequest product = new CustomerRequest(user_id,name,price,image,outletname);
                                productList.add(product);

                            }

                            //   adapter = new ProductAdapter(MainActivity.this,productList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }



}
----------------------------
adapterclass
public class CustomerRequestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerRequestAdapter.ProductViewHolder>  {
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<CustomerRequest> customerRequestList;
    //HashMap<String,String> modelList;

    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://192.168.10.119/staradmin/andcustomeradd.php";

    String UseridHolder;





    public CustomerRequestAdapter(Context mCtx, List<CustomerRequest> customerRequestList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.customerRequestList = customerRequestList;
       // this.modelList = modelList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custrequest, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final CustomerRequest customerRequest = customerRequestList.get(position);

        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(customerRequest.getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.textViewId.setText(customerRequest.getUser_id());
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(customerRequest.getName());
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(customerRequest.getPrice());
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(customerRequest.getCity());
        holder.textViewOutlet.setText(customerRequest.getOutletname());


        holder.accept.setTag(R.id.accept);
        holder.reject.setTag(R.id.reject);

       holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           String  i = customerRequest.getUser_id();

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           final String   URL_PRODUCTS = "http://192.168.10.119/staradmin/andcustomeradd.php";

               final String i = customerRequest.getUser_id();
               UseridHolder = i.toString().trim();

              // Toast.makeText(mCtx,UseridHolder,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               //Toast.makeText(mCtx,String.valueOf(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               //  Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx,MainActivity.class);
               // intent.putExtra("user_id",customerRequest.getUser_id());
               //  mCtx.startActivity(intent);

               StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_PRODUCTS,
                       new Response.Listener<String>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onResponse(String response) {

                               if(response.contains("true")){
                                   Toast.makeText(mCtx,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               }else{
                                   Toast.makeText(mCtx,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               }

                           }
                       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       Toast.makeText(mCtx,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               }
               ){

                   @Override
                   protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                       Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                       params.put("i",UseridHolder);
                       return params;
                   }
               };

               Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx).add(stringRequest);
           }

       });


        holder.reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String k = customerRequest.getUser_id();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mCtx,String.valueOf(k),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return customerRequestList.size();
    }


    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView textViewTitle, textViewPrice, textViewOutlet, textViewId;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button accept, reject;

        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
            textViewOutlet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOutlet);
            textViewId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            accept = itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept);
            reject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reject);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }

}
-----------------
class
public class CustomerRequest {

    private String user_id;
    private String name,city,price,outletname;
  //  double price;
    private String image;

    public CustomerRequest(String user_id, String name, String price, String image, String outletname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
        this.outletname = outletname;
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getOutletname() {
        return outletname;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Either your problem is you are unable to get the id when the user hits the button or problem while sending the data

```
class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textViewTitle, textViewPrice, textViewOutlet, textViewId;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button accept, reject;

    RelativeLayout parentLayout;

    public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
        textViewOutlet = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOutlet);
        textViewId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        accept = itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept);
        reject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reject);


       accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //send the id
                customerRequest.getUser_id();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know after you try this I did this concept before @Sunil

Comment: Hello sir Brahma, I am getting the user id. My problem is not able to send that user id to database. Only null values are reaching to php,and my sql

Comment: sir Tested your code customerrequest.getuser id not working.

Comment: Are you getting the data from server clearly? @SunilKumarReddy

Comment: If the getUserId is not working either the issue might be from the server or you are having the issue to get that id from the server @SunilKumarReddy

Comment: I am getting data from server above holder.accept(On bindview holder). But  I am not able pass it to database using hashmap in adapter file.

Comment: you are not setting the id in the model class. You are using get methods but not the set methods. Then how can you get the id without setting the id in CustomerRequest @SunilKumarReddy

Comment: Thanks for extending your help. Issue is resolved. Its working now